# Handle different git patches?

Tags: git

Example: I have a repo where I commit; I have my branch and I do work on a feature.
I do iterate changes on the same files, using --amend. Then I try to do something different, so I commit a new change, which will create a different entry with a different commit message (say I add a new function that I want to experiment.

Now the problem is: if I want to go back to my previous work, before the creation of this new patch, how do I do that?

If I commit new changes, even using --amend, they will go on the latest patch, not on the previous. Do I have to do a hard reset on the previous commit? And if I do so, do I loose the code changes made in the other patch?

To summarize:

```
make changes-->commit to A with --amend (the changes go on the same patch
changes with new function--> commit B (new commit message)
changes--> commit A --amend (changes goes to B now)
```

now the changes will go in commit B, even using --amend instead of commit A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
git stash # Put all the changes aside for a moment
git rebase --interactive COMMIT # Switch to the commit you want to amend
git stash pop # Pull all the changes back so the commit can be amended
git commit --amend # Amend it
git rebase --continue # Rebase everything commited after the amended commit
                      # so that it looks like the changes were always there
```

Note however that in addition to changing hash of the amended commit, this changes hashes of all rebased commits as well so this should be avoided when the commits have already been pushed upstream. In that case, you have not much choice but to make a new commit.

Comment: Thanks; I see a lots of things that could go wrong with this; probably is better to just check out in a different directory and make a totally separated patch, each one on its own folder.